# CountDownTimer behaves weird/different the second time i open its Activity

Tags: countdowntimer

I have been spending way too many hours on this one. And i just dont get it.

What i want: I have a main Activity (lets call it 'Activity Main') from which i am calling a second Activity ('Activity Timer') that has a CountDownTimer. Upon starting "Activity Timer" i want a Countdown to start running; it is only supposed to play a sound when it finishes. There is also a 'Pause-Button' which pauses/resumes the Countdown. 'Activity Timer' sends back results to 'Activity Main' via Intent when a button is pressed (either 'Success' or 'Fail' - well, it's a game). I am back at 'Activity Main' and all just worked perfectly fine.

That is until i start 'Activity Timer' a second time (for the secound round): The Countdown starts but cannot be paused. It just keeps ticking, even though i cancel() the Countdown and finish() the 'Activity Timer'.

Here's the code:

> Activity Timer

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    long countdown_time;
    Button button_fail, button_success;
    ImageButton imgbtn_pause;
    boolean cd_running = false;
    boolean countdown_auto = true;
    TextView textView_countdown;
    private static CountDownTimer;
    Vibrator vibrator;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        // Preferences
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("shared_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Intent
        Intent i = getIntent();
        countdown_time = i.getLongExtra("countdown_time", 60000);

        // Assigning
        button_fail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fail);
        button_success = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_success);
        textView_countdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_countdown);
        imgbtn_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_pause);

        button_fail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (cd_running) {
                    countdown.cancel();
                }

                cd_running = false;
                countdown = null;
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

                if (risk) {
                    returnIntent.putExtra("result", "-3");
                } else {
                    returnIntent.putExtra("result", "0");
                }

                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        button_success.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (cd_running) {
                    countdown.cancel();
                }

                cd_running = false;
                countdown = null;
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        imgbtn_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (cd_running) {
                    countdown.cancel();
                    cd_running = false;
                    imgbtn_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_2);
                } else {
                    startCountDownTimer();
                    imgbtn_risk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imgbtn_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_2);
                }
            }
        });

        private void startCountDownTimer() {

        cd_running = true;
        imgbtn_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_2);

        countdown = new CountDownTimer(countdown_time, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                countdown_time = millisUntilFinished;
                textView_countdown.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                countdown.cancel();
                countdown = null;
                cd_running = false;

                if (!mute) {
                    vibrator = (Vibrator) GameActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                    countdown_sound.start();
                }
                textView_countdown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                textView_gameOver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgbtn_pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

> The call from 'Activity Main':

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(GameMenu.this, GameActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("countdown_time", countdown_time);

                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                }
    }

     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                String result_string = data.getStringExtra("result");
                int result_int = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("result"));

            }

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // No result
            }
    }
```